# Building and installing a kernel that can mount / from an EXT3 on an LVM2 device

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm, linux-kernel

I have an ageing but much loved Fedora Core 6 box for which I am attempting to compile a kernel more recent than 2.6.22, in order that I might employ its support for an eSATA card.

My Fedora box has a pair of 500G disks & uses LVM2 to pool most of their content into a large root file system. Together they form /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00. All kernels reside in /boot which is on a more traditional /dev/sda1.

Once the newer kernel boots it very quickly cannot find /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00 and panics, complaining that it cannot find /dev/root.

I have built my kernel using the config file '/boot/config-2.6.22.14-72.fc6' as inspiration, hoping that whichever arcane switch I needed would be set, but so far - in vain.

I am resisting the urge to upgrade something more recent, as that's quite a hammer to break a very small egg.

Your clues & boos are all most welcome,

M.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't hae device-mapper built into the kernel, as a module or possibly built into your new kernel's initrd file for use on boot. Check your config for the _DM options:

```
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM=y
CONFIG_DM_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_DM_CRYPT=m
CONFIG_DM_SNAPSHOT=y
CONFIG_DM_MIRROR=y
CONFIG_DM_LOG_USERSPACE=m
CONFIG_DM_ZERO=y
CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH=m
CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH_QL=m
CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH_ST=m
CONFIG_DM_UEVENT=y
```

If it's built as a module, switch it to built in or 'mkinitrd --with=dm_mod' (sic) to get it in there.

http://sources.redhat.com/dm/

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The answer in the end was to set this in the .config

```
CONFIG_SYSFS_DEPRECATED_V2=y
```